# How to catch the window close event in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I working on a flutter windows application. I need to show an alert box when closing the application also I need to kill another process when closing this application. Is there any way to catch the window_close event on flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this package supports all windows events.

https://pub.dev/packages/window_manager

here is the method link

https://pub.dev/packages/window_manager#onwindowclose